# Finding out the number of digits to changed in binary number to make it equivalent to decimal number

Tags: javascript

I have been trying a coding challenge but could not think of the logic for it.

The question was like in a function you were given and arguement which was an
array containing info like

> [ 56 , 011000 ]

so when we run this function the output was 1 as only 1 digit needs to be changed in binary  (i,e 011000) to make that equivalent to 56.

Similarily the other test case was

> [ 44 , 111111 ]

which expected output to be 3 as only 3 digits needs to be changes in binary number to make it equivalent to 44.

I could not even think of the logic so would be better if someone helps me out :)

Comment: Check the documentation of [`Number.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

Comment: _"but what i want to see is how do u people use logic here"_ - We're here to help with your code and not to write the complete answer for you.

Comment: yeah @MisterJojo thanks a ton

Comment: Should "101" (3digits) and "1" (1 single digit) return 1 or 2? - in other words, should the missing zeros be counted? if so, the solution of
Aziz Sonawalla is bad, otherwise it's mine. I also commented on the use of octal in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this question:

1. Convert the decimal number to binary
2. Find the number of differing digits between the two binary strings

For the first part, you can use the `toString(2)` method as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Number/toString). For example:

```js
console.log(Number(22).toString(2)); // prints "10110"
```

Or you can write your own function for that. One way to do that is, for a decimal number n, keep finding the highest power of 2 that is less than or equal to n, and then subtract that from n.

For the second part, you can iterate over both strings as follows:

```js
let binaryString1 = "101";
let binaryString2 = Number(22).toString(2); // "10110"

const maxLen = Math.max(binaryString1.length, binaryString2.length); // get the length of the longer string

// make sure both strings are of the same length
binaryString1 = binaryString1.padStart(maxLen, "0");
binaryString2 = binaryString2.padStart(maxLen, "0");

let diff = 0;
for (let i=0; i < maxLen; i++) {
    if (binaryString1.charAt(i) !== binaryString2.charAt(i)) {
        diff++;
    }
}
console.log(diff); // prints the number of differing chars
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had `.len` instead of `.length`. Fixed it.

Comment: I'm not sure that filling in with leading zeros is a good idea ...

Comment: Isn't that for OP to decide? It depends on what the question specifies. If OP doesn't want to pad it, they can choose not to.

Comment: Yes, it's OP who decides, and that's precisely why I asked him the question. His text is very imprecise, I'm just warning him, and you too, because I don't believe you were aware of it either.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for this?

(there is a lack of information in your message)

> for information 01100 represent an octal value
> **01100 === 0o1100 === 576 === 0b1001000000000**

this is just 5 lines of code...

```js
function pairTest (arr2v)
  {
  let v0 = [...arr2v[0].toString(2)].reverse()  // make 2 binary string reverse array
    , v1 = [...arr2v[1].toString(10)].reverse() // for Right to Left testing
  return v0.reduce((d,v,i)=>
    d +((!!v1[i])?v!==v1[i]:1)          // test digits, if exist in v1 otherwise add 1
    ,Math.max(0, v1.length-v0.length))  // if v1 is longer, the start value is the difference
  }

console.log( pairTest([ 56 , 11000 ]) )  // -> 1
console.log( pairTest([ 44 , 111111 ]) )  // -> 3
```

Comment: Too much white-space, too less ES6, way too much characters,... /s An actual explanation of your answer, in a more verbose and easier understandable version would help future readers and possibly OP